# Operations on a graph using pyvis with python

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx, pyvis

I have defined a graph by using `from pyvis.network import Network` and defining a network as `net = Network()`.

I added to the net edges and nodes using the functions `net.add_nodes(nodes)` and `net.add_edge(x, y)`. There is any chance to deal with this graph not only using a visualization? So for e.g. to find all paths between two specific nodes? Because searching in the documentation there is only the possibility to plot the graph. I saw other options (e.g. class) to deal with graphs ([example](https://python-course.eu/applications-python/graphs-python.php)) but is very annoying to define the graph with a dict of a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`pyvis`](https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) documentation:

> The pyvis library is meant for quick generation of visual network graphs with minimal python code. It is designed as a wrapper around the popular Javascript visJS library found at this link.

You probably want a library such as [`networkx`](https://networkx.org), which you probably have tagged by accident. It's description states

> NetworkX is a Python package for the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks.

This includes many operations, see the [tutorial](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) or to take your example: [shortest path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html)

Comment: It is better to use networkx or i-graph (https://igraph.org/python/)?

Comment: I have not much experience with `igraph`, but would simply recommend that you check both documentation and check with your requirements. `Networkx` is pure python with a very good documentation. `igraph` is based on C (hence faster to run, but modification of the graph more costly). Transformation between both on the graph level are anyways available.